# simple users edit in panel admin in c# by text file as data base

Tags: c#

my code don't change anything in the file.
here's my code.
i try to find the name of the user by idx of line and than to change the needed change but the txt file stay as he was ,the method "read names" reading the names of all the people by split and its works.
read file method read all the lines to array of lines.
update arr is method that get the new lines array and replace it with the first one.
findidxbyusename find the idx of the line of the selected username

```
public string[] readNames()
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/aab/passwords.txt");
    string tmpName;
    string[] arr = new string[lines.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        tmpName = lines[i].Split(new[] { ",", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
        arr[i] = tmpName;
    }
    return arr;
}
public string[] readFile()
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/aab/passwords.txt");
    return lines;
}

public void updateArr(string[] arr)
{
    string content = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        content += arr[i] + "\r\n";
    }
    File.WriteAllText("c:/aab/passwords.txt", content);
}


public int FindidxOfUser(string username)
{
    string[] arr = readFile();
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].Split(new[] { ",", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Equals(username))
        {
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    return idx;
}

private void usersEdit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = readNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(arr[i]);
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text.Equals("User name"))
    {
        label2.Text = "New User Name :";
        textBox1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "New Password :";
        textBox1.Visible = true;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = comboBox2.Text;
    int idx = FindidxOfUser(username);
    string[] arr = readFile();
    if (comboBox1.Text.Equals("User name"))
    {
        arr[idx].Split(',')[0] = textBox1.Text;
        updateArr(arr);
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text + " Changed Succesfully!", "Succes!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text.Equals("Password"))
    {
        arr[idx].Split(',')[1] = textBox1.Text;
        updateArr(arr);
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text + " Changed Succesfully!", "Succes!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Shlomi you are a dom ass", "Succes!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is why its not working

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually assigning the value to the arr[idx] string with the following code:

```
arr[idx].Split(',')[0] = textBox1.Text
```

It is actually splitting the string which creates a string array, and then setting the first value to the textbox text. You aren't actually assigning a value to the arr[idx] string but instead the in-memory array of strings. It's a subtle difference but the reason your code isn't working.

You can change the line to the following to make it "stick":

```
string[] arrElements = arr[idx].Split(',');
arrElements[0] = textBox1.Text;
arr[idx] = String.Join(arrElements, ",");
updateArr(arr);
```

You would then need to do the same where you are setting the password. The key is that you are assigning the value to the actual arr[idx] this way rather than the temporary string array from the split.

Comment: but the string.join need in the first parameter string not an array